# How do I give mvim Full Disk Access on macOS?

Tags: macvim, macos

How can I use `mvim` to open files that require extra permissions on macOS?

I've given MacVim Full Disk Access in "Security & Privacy":
[image: I've given MacVim Full Disk Access]

That allows me to open MacVim (by double clicking it in Finder) and edit files `:edit ~/Documents/test.md` without issue.

**However**, when I use `mvim ~/Documents/test.md` to open the file in MacVim from Terminal, MacVim says `"~/Documents/test.md" [Permission Denied]`. (And Terminal is unable to tab complete the filename.)

I can even quit the MacVim instance opened by `mvim` and open a new one and edit the file.

I get the same issue if I `mvim` and then `:edit ~/Documents/test.md`.

I also tried adding `/usr/local/bin/mvim` to Full Disk Access, quit MacVim, and open test.md and same error.

So how can I let **mvim** open these files too?

Answer (score 1):

You also need to give Terminal Full Disk Access.

I guess applications launched from Terminal will be limited to Terminal's permissions.